# Deploy AppIdentityService class App engine in PHP

Tags: php, google-app-engine

My code is in App engine Standard I´m just trying to use AppIdentityService

```
<?php
  use google\appengine\api\app_identity\AppIdentityService;
  $email = AppIdentityService::getServiceAccountName();
  print($email);
?>
```

But the next error appears Uncaught Error: Class 'google\appengine\api\app_identity\AppIdentityService' not found in

Is there any step I´m missing?

Comment: Try to use `require('path to google class.php');` instead `use google\appengine\api\app_identity\AppIdentityService;`

Comment: There are a lot of files that are somethingclass.php do you know which is it?

Comment: I think it must be AppIdentityServiceclass.php or you can find file, with `class AppIdentityService`